# What are some weak conditions we can put on $f \in L^1$ so that the Fourier transform of $f$ is in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I know that if $f \in L^{\infty}$ then its Fourier transform is in $L^1$. I am curious if there are some other known weak conditions one may ask of $f$ to ensure that its Fourier transform is in $L^1$.

Comment: "I know that if $f\in L^\infty$ then its Fourier transform is in $L^1$". I guess it is time to refresh your knowledge...

Comment: No, $f\in L^\infty$ does not imply $\hat f\in L^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about the Fourier transform on the line, the simplest thing I can think of is $f,f'\in L^2$.

**Note:** If $f,\hat f\in L^1$ then there is a continuous function $g$ with $f=g$ almost everywhere; this should make it clear that  $f\in L^\infty\cap L^1$ does not imply $\hat f\in  L^1$.